# Near cache miss

Tags: ignite, near-cache

I have a ignite near cache client with say size of 100(LRU). The cluster behind it has an LRU policy for on-heap with size 10K. Say any record got evicted from the near cache due to the small size of it UPDATE1(but is there in main cluster cache).

Will any subsequent get on near cache load the data from cluster cache?

Answer (score 1):

The near cache and the server-side on-heap cache are just... caches. If the values get evicted then the next time you access them, they'll be brought into memory. Something else may be evicted to make room.

Comment: if data is evicted from near cache but is there in backing cluster cache, will near cache load it from main cluster cache?

Comment: Yes, when you next request the data.